# Trigger After Insert ....to Update a Count(column)

Tags: mysql

I have a table "Comments" and a copy of it, call #Comments_copy (surprise!).
The table "comments" is linked to another one call #article" by a foreigner key as: comments.article_id = article.id.

In Comments_copy: I have a column COUNT(Comments_id).

I try to create a trigger AFTER INSERT into comments which will update the count in comments_copy.

I JUST begin in MySQL so I'm a bit lost in my code.

I guess my problem comes from my condition "WHERE". But I feel clueless to find out the right condition... :(

```
CREATE TABLE Comments_copy 
SELECT Comments.id as C_id, article.id, COUNT(Comments.id) as Nb_comments
FROM Comments
RIGHT JOIN Article ON article.id = Comments.article_id 
GROUP BY Article.id
ORDER BY Article.id ;

DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_comments AFTER INSERT
ON comments FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Comments_copy
    SET Nb_comments = Nb_comments +1
    WHERE id = NEW.id ;

END |

DELIMITER ;
```

At the end, I expect to recalculate the count of comments JUST for the article concerned by the last comments entry.

Comment: 'I guess my problem' - what problem would that be then?

Comment: Nothing happens when I try to insert something.

Comment: Please examine your comments_copy table (using show create table or describe table) and add the output of the show create table to the question. Do you see a column called id? And if you do does it match how you are inserting?

Answer (score 0):

Please try in this way.

Please notice that I changed `END |` to `END; |`

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_comments 
AFTER INSERT ON comments 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   UPDATE Comments_copy 
    SET Nb_comments = Nb_comments +1 
   WHERE id = NEW.id ;
 END; |
```

Comment: How is this different the ops trigger?

Comment: @LilyZen what is the error message? The sql lookd ok

Comment: There is no error... But when I check my table after an insertion, nothing happens.

Comment: @Simonare Even if I create the trigger AFTER insert ? I mean, does the id should be available AFTER the insert ?

Comment: I double checked it. It must be available. I am not sure what would it be since everyrhing looks ok